# Existence of distribution for certain order statistics

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

This is an open question: given a sequence of $n$ real numbers $x_1<x_2<\dots<x_n$, does there always exist a probability distribution, such that $\{x_i\}$ happens to be the $n$ *expected order statistics* of this distribution?

In other words, can we always "reverse engineer" the distribution from its expected order statistics? Note that there is **no restrictions** on the distribution, i.e., it can be continuous, discrete, or whatever. I wonder if anything is known regarding this existence problem.

---

(Edited 09/20/2017)

When sequence $\{x_i\}$ is unrestricted, the answer to above claim is **no**. This is shown by @Mateusz Kwaśnicki when $n=4$. However, under $n=4$, suppose $\{x_i\}$ satisfies the condition that $3(x_4−x_1)⩽7(x_3−x_2)$, then is there a method that can construct the distribution for which $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ are the expected order statistics?

In other words, suppose $\{x_i\}$ satisfies the necessary conditions to be expected order statistics, is there a method to "reconstruct" the underlying distribution? Or is this too much to ask for?

Comment: By the $k$-th *expected* order statistic I assume you mean the expectation value of the $k$-smallest value. But then you need to modify the question to ask "do there always exist a probability distribution **and a sample size** $s$ such that $\{x_i\}$ for $1\leq i \leq n$ happens to be the $i$-th expected order statistic for samples of size $s$ from that distribution."

Comment: Or you might be asking for a distribution where the expected value of the $n$ order statistics for samples of size $n$ is the sequence $\{x_i\}$. It that the question?

Comment: I tried {1,2,9} as an experiment, and found an approximate answer for that case:  .894 + 1594 Beta[1/8, 64].  I didn't find it easy.

Comment: @MattF. Could you elaborate a bit on how you find that approximation? Thanks!

Comment: @MarkFischler I'm referring to the expectations of order statistics. Specifically, for a given distribution, randomly and independently draw $n$ numbers, then rank them - I'm interested in the _expected_ value of each one of these $n$ random variables. Does this clarify your question?

Comment: I used trial and error with beta's to get the needed value of 7 for $(X(3)-X(2)) / (X(2)-X(1))$, and then scaled linearly to get the 1, 2 and 9.  And before that I used trial and error to find a good family of distributions to fit parameters.

Comment: If your original question was answered to your satisfaction, I suggest making new posts for any follow-up questions (giving a link to this question, of course).

Comment: @j.c. Thanks! I'm new to this but will keep in mind to do so next time!

Comment: @user3026001 it's not too late to do so this time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is **no** when $n = 4$.

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ be a sample from a distribution with CDF $F$. Denote by $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4$ the order statistics (that is, the non-decreasing rearrangement) of $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$, and let $x_j = \mathbb{E} X_j$. We will show that $3(x_4-x_1) \leqslant 7(x_3-x_2)$.

The CDFs $F_j$ of $Y_j$ are given by
$$\begin{aligned}
F_1 & = F^4 , & F_2 & = 4 F^3 - 3 F^4 , \\
F_3 & = 6 F^2 - 8 F^3 + 3 F^4 , \qquad & F_4 & = 4 F - 6 F^2 + 4 F^3 - F^4 .
\end{aligned}$$
Since $x_j = \mathbb{E} Y_j = \int_{-\infty}^\infty t \, dF_j(t)$, we have
$$
 3(x_4-x_1) - 7(x_3-x_2) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty t \, dG(t) ,
$$
where
$$
 G = 3F_4-7F_3+7F_2-3F_1 = 12 F - 60 F^2 + 96 F^3 - 48 F^4 = 12 F (1 - F) (1 - 2 F)^2.
$$
Observe that $t F(t)$ and $t (1 - F(t))$ converge to zero as $t \to -\infty$ and $t \to \infty$, respectively (because the distribution with CDF $F$ has finite mean). Therefore, $t G(t)$ converges to zero as $t \to \pm \infty$. Integration by parts leads to
$$
 3(x_4-x_1) - 7(x_3-x_2) = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(t) dt .
$$
However, $G = 12 F(1 - F)(1 - 2F)^2 \geqslant 0$, and so the right-hand side is non-positive, as claimed.

---

Interestingly, the answer to the original question is **yes** if $n = 3$, and it is enough to consider two-point distributions. Indeed, if $x_1 < x_2 < x_3$ and
$$\begin{aligned}
p & = \frac{x_3-x_2}{x_3-x_1}, & a & = \frac{3 x_1 x_3 - x_1^2 - x_1 x_2 - x_2^2}{3 (x_3 - x_2)} , & b & = \frac{x_2^2 + x_2 x_3 + x_3^2 - 3 x_1 x_3}{3 (x_2 - x_1)} ,
\end{aligned}$$
then $x_1, x_2, x_3$ are expected values of the order statistics of a sample of three random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(X = a) = p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X = b) = 1 - p$. This can be verified by a direct calculation, an important point is that $b - a = (x_3 - x_1)^3 / (3 (x_3 - x_2) (x_2 - x_1)) > 0$.

Comment: Nice argument! I would like to ask a follow-up question. Please the edited question.

Comment: @user3026001: The restriction discussed above is clearly not sufficient. You can easily find other inequalities of a similar kind by finding other linear combinations of $F_j$ with coefficients that add up to zero that are negative functions of $F \in [0,1]$. Does this family of linear conditions give an "if and only if" condition? I would not be surprised if this was the case. Can one write down these conditions in a systematic way? I have no idea.

Comment: @user3026001: Regarding the construction, apparently it is sufficient to consider discrete distributions. A systematic way could be the following: consider random variables satisfying $\mathbb{P}(X=a_j)=\tfrac{1}{k}$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,k$ and $a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_k$. Then expectations of the order statistics $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ are linear combinations of $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$ (with fairly explicit coefficients). You can solve it for the unknown $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$, remembering that $a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_k$. If no such solution exists, increase $k$ and try again.